# PowerBI TopN filter with Tie

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've encountered a situation where there is a tie when i aplly a TopN filter on a PowerBI visual. It will display > the "N" number of items I want to see. Is there a way to limit the number to always only show only the "TopN"?

For example, assume I have both an online store and a physical store for my business. I want to promote the usage of my online store and analyze who is my top grower in terms of webstore usage as compare to prior years.

Relevant measures include:

1. Total Sales this year.
2. Total Websale this year.
3. Websale% this year = measure2 / measure1
4. Total Sales prior year.
5. Total Websale prior year.
6. Websale% prior year = measure5 / measure4
7. Websale% difference = Websale% this year - Websale% prior year

If I want to analyze the top 5 growers in terms of website usage as compare to prior year, I may use measure7 to calculate the percentage difference. (eg. Last year customer A has a websale % of 5%, this year is 25%, so the difference is 20%)

However, this might not be the best measure to use because if customer A bought nothing last year, and bought a $1 item only this year, and its from the website. The websale% difference would be 100%. And a lot of the customers are like that, so it not only causes my TopN filters to not work due to ties. But its also a not meaningful measure when i want to analyze customers with potential. Because clearly a customer who spend $10000 with a websale% difference of 50% would be more meaningful than customers who only spend $1 but with 100% on websale% difference.

Could anyone help me with a more meaningful measure to not only address the TopN filter issue and be able to analyze a better customer group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a visual filter on the table for when total sales > x thousand. This should remove those smaller players that have a big % growth, but were insignificant to total sales.